# c# Binding ComboBoxList to SqlCe Database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

This is more of an understanding / clarification question than a technical one. I am currently trying to bind some data from a database to a ComboBoxList.

The datatabase is an SqlCe type. It's called voodoobase.sdf. It is listed under Server Explorer along with all its tables.

**Q1**) What is the correct procedure to bind a dropdown ComboBoxList to the data in the database?

Do you have to go through Data Sources?

What is a Model container?

I am used to PHP/MySQL where you just connect and do it all yourself. If you have any good clear links or are able to answer this in a human readable way I would be grateful.

I am close to figuring this all out, but I think just I need to put it all together.

**Q2**) The databse was designed and comes in Solution Explorer as a DBModel.edmx. If I make changes here and "Generate Database From Model" It seems to update the Database (which is good) but Data Sources do not update with it ? <-- is this a correct feature?

I know this is wordy question but if you can shed some clarity on this would make me happy =))

Comment: you might get better responses by splitting this into multiple questions?  i count 2 numbered and at least 2 non-numbered questions in this one question :)

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**:
This is a fairly roundabout way maybe, but this is how i do it for a combobox:

1. Create a dataset for the database (when i added my sqlce db, i chose to add a dataset during the wizard that automatically popped up)
2. Open your dataset by doubleclicking on it
3. From your "Server Explorer", create your tables & edit your data as needed, then drag & drop your table/s to the dataset designer
4. Open your windows form's design view and from your "Data Sources" (which should have your dataset in it), drag & drop some fields that you'd want to display for this table on to your form (e.g. name, surname, age, gender, etc). Visual Studio will then auto-add the following objects (visible on the bottom of your design view): dataset, bindingsource, table adapter and a table adapter manager.
5. Now add your Combobox that you want to bind to this table (e.g "cboName")
6. In code-behind in the Form_Load event, bind it as follows:
   cboName.DataSource = myTableBindingSource;
   cboName.DisplayMember = "Name"; //will bind to the "Name" column

That should be it. Now when the app runs you'll be able to select the people by name from the combobox and their details will show accordingly in the other controls you dropped on the form. I'm still very new to this, so there might be better ways. But this works for me so far :). Unfortunately i'm not sure what a model container is.

**Q2:**
I'm not sure about edmx database models. My database is an sdf file, my dataset is an xsd file and i edit my database through the Server Explorer.

...However VERY important to know is that your "designed" database is not the db your app is using in runtime. Go check your bin folder - in there you'll find the db your app runs with. (With SQLCE the database in design is seperated from the db used and you have to manually update (copy-paste overwrite) your db in the bin folder after changes made in your design or data).

Take note that your "data sources" is like a map to your database. You'll have to update (drag-dropping your table again)... or recreate, etc. the data source (e.g. your dataset) if your db changes doesn't reflect on it.